# Reviewboard installation with Apache, shows files instead of site

Tags: apache-2.4, python, django

Installing reviewboard on centos 7.

Web server : Apache running on port 8080

After i finished the installation it shows me directory listing when i access it from browser.

Below is my apache-wsgi.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
ServerName reviews.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/reviews.com/htdocs"

# Error handlers
ErrorDocument 500 /errordocs/500.html

WSGIPassAuthorization On
WSGIScriptAlias "/reviews" "/var/www/html/reviews.com/htdocs/reviewboard.wsgi/reviews"

<Directory "/var/www/html/reviews.com/htdocs">
    AllowOverride All
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Prevent the server from processing or allowing the rendering of
# certain file types.
<Location "/reviews/media/uploaded">
    SetHandler None
    Options None

    AddType text/plain .html .htm .shtml .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phps .asp
    AddType text/plain .pl .py .fcgi .cgi .phtml .phtm .pht .jsp .sh .rb

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_flag engine off
    </IfModule>

    # Force all uploaded media files to download.
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Content-Disposition "attachment"
    </IfModule>
</Location>

# Alias static media requests to filesystem
Alias /reviews/media "/var/www/html/reviews.com/htdocs/media"
Alias /reviews/static "/var/www/html/reviews.com/htdocs/static"
Alias /reviews/errordocs "/var/www/html/reviews.com/htdocs/errordocs"
Alias /reviews/favicon.ico "/var/www/html/reviews.com/htdocs/static/rb/images/favicon.png"
```

What is the issue and how to fix it.

Comment: If the default page of a website is not named `index.html` (case-sensitive) you need to either rename that page or add the file-name for that default page with the [`DirectoryIndex`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) directive.

Comment: i have tried to run the file by selecting the file in directory listing but it just displays source code on browser.